# Automate translation between string and his equivalent variable in PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to store templates as html string with PHP variables in my DB.
So far I'm already storing things like that

```
<p>Hi</p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p>This is case n&deg; {{$surgery-&gt;id}} and the user responsible is <b>Dr. {{$surgery-&gt;surgeon-&gt;lastname}}</b></p>
```

In my controller I use something like this

```
$template = \App\Template::find(1); //Get text from DB

$output = preg_replace_callback('~\{\{(.*?)\}\}~', //Manage only var between {{ and }}
            function($key)
            {
                $surgery = \App\Surgery::find(1);

                $variable['$surgery->id'] = $surgery->id;
                $variable['$surgery->surgeon->lastname'] = $surgery->surgeon->lastname;
                //...

                return $variable[$key[1]];
            },
            htmlspecialchars_decode($template->html)); //Decode the HTML

return view('home' , compact('output'));
```

And in my view I use

```
{!! $ouput !!}
```

This is all working fine but I'm asking how can I improve this script to automate the translation between `$variable['$surgery->id']` and `$surgery->id` because there are a lot of relations and I don't want to write them all.

I tried that

```
function($key)
{
    $surgery = \App\Surgery::find(1);

    $test = substr($key[1], 10); //Get only string after $surgery->

    $variable['$surgery->' . $test] = $surgery->$test;

    return $variable[$key[1]];
}
```

It is working for direct relation like `$surgery->id` ou `$surgery->name`
but not when there are many "arrows" so when this an attribute of a relation like `$surgery->relation->attribute`

Comment: you can store the value of `{{ $entity->id }}` in db when saving html content

Comment: you can't use `{{}}` inside another `{{}}`

Comment: then use `Components & Slots` https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#components-and-slots

Comment: @Sohel0415 I found a way to do this and edited my question

Comment: how??make a answer, it may help others

Comment: @Sohel0415 I wrote the function

Comment: will see this later on my free time, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to render and parse a php variable at the same time. The string containing the variables needs to be built before it goes to the template compiler.

As you have it it's too late to inject more php.